# calculate mortgage in python?

Tags: python, function

so i have this program that calculate that calculates the total amount that Dave will have to pay over the life of the mortgage:

```
    # mortgage.py

principal = 500000.0
rate = 0.05
payment = 2684.11
total_paid = 0.0

while principal > 0:
principal = principal * (1+rate/12) - payment
total_paid = total_paid + payment

print('Total paid', total_paid)
```

and later the exercise ask me Suppose Dave pays an extra $1000/month for the first 12 months of the mortgage?

Modify the program to incorporate this extra payment and have it print the total amount paid along with the number of months required.
what can i modify to make the changes to the program ? I am lost

Comment: I won't give you the straight coded answer but you're being asked to add a second condition to your program. The first condition is that there is still principal to be paid (n.b. what happens if principal is less than the regular payment for the last payment?), you now need to add a condition that incorporates time. Consider perhaps how you could use `if...else` here...

Comment: you have to break down your problem in 2 different components, the part where there is extra payment and the part without it, and then figure out how to put it together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
principal=500000.0
rate= 0.0

payment = 2684.11
total_paid = 0.0

extra_payment = 1000.0
num_periods = 0
while principal > 0:
    if num_periods < 12:
        principal = principal * (1+rate/12) - (payment+extra_payment)
        total_paid += payment + extra_payment
    else:
        principal = principal * (1+rate/12) - (payment)
        total_paid += payment
    num_periods += 1
print('Total paid: $', total_paid)
```

Total paid = 929965.6199999959,
but principal = -1973.205724763917

You have overpayed the final payment
remember to add 'principal' to 'total_paid' to get the actual amount:
927992.414275232

Also, the numbers are not rounded to 2 decimal places
you can round them by using:

```
def twoDecimalPlaces(answer):
    return("%.2f" % answer)


twoDecimalPlaces(927992.414275232)
>>> 927992.41
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to ask again to the user "Do Dave has paid anything extra in principal amount?" if Yes then create new variable for updated principal
update_principal = principal + dave_paid_extra
and then re run the code with same eqaution.

Comment: the answer isn't clear, you might try to write code expresions in code text style, and adapt to question. here it's clear that there's a condition over this `paid_extra`